# How are Ruby Blocks implemented (in a compiler)

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction, scopes

I want to implement a language construct similiar to Ruby´s blocks. So

```
main()
{
    i = 123
    array.function(|x| { puts x + i; }) //the block needs access to the local variable i
}
```

should compile fine. I looked at the source code for 1 hour but since I´m not that good at C I still have no idea how they implement it. My first thought was it is a nested function which address gets passed as a parameter, but I´m not sure how the nested function has access to the local variable because it seems in most languages this isnt possible. If anyone can give me an idea of how to implement this I would be very glad

Comment: Can you push the associated stack onto the new function's when it's invoked?

Comment: when I call a function I just push the parameters (each has 4 byte) onto the stack and make a call which pushes the return address on the ras.

Comment: Blocks *can* be implemented as anonymous functions; however, if they are not lifted in the called function (there is no `&block`) then they *could* be declared/simulated entirely on the current frame ..

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean by "frame", do you mean the function prolog/epilog? currently it looks like this for me stackFrame.push(bp); bp = sp; sp -= *(int*)ip;

Comment: @MoritzSchöfl The call-stack of the containing function. However this requires knowledge that the block *isn't* lifted inside the callee ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is implementation of code blocks and yields in C, it may help you.
http://tilarids.blogspot.com/2012/03/ruby-like-blocks-and-yield-keyword-in-c.html

Comment: Interesting and scary .. it's a shame more language didn't adopt LISP-like ("AST") Macros :(